# AJAX Call to Remote Page and Sessions

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am messing around with AJAX again and am having troubles passing data to PHP.

**Context:**

What I wish to do is make my alert boxes using AJAX rather than refreshing the whole page every time an alert box closes.

**The Code:**

**The JavaScript:**

```
  var endpoint = './ajax-call.php';

  $('.close').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().fadeOut(500, function(){
      var classes = $(this).attr("class").split(" ");
      var alertid = classes[classes.length - 1];

      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: endpoint,
        data: {f: 'removealert', id: alertid},
        cache: false
      });
    });
  });
```

**The PHP:**

```
  function removeAlert($alertindex){
    unset($_SESSION['alerts'][$alertindex]);
  }
```

**The Middleware (Also PHP):**

```
  if($_POST['f'] == 'removealert'){
    removeAlert(intval($_POST['id']));
  }
```

I know the AJAX data is being sent thanks to the Google Chrome console. I also know that the PHP function removeAlert($alertid) also works because I have tested that. However, the PHP function does not work so I think it's something to do with the middleware code.

I've been at this for hours and can't seem to see the error. Thanks in advance. If you need any more information let me know.

Comment: I can't understand what effect on client side do you expect by `unset($_SESSION['alerts'][$alertindex])` at server and no ajax callback in javascript? - To check the php function execution you can put an `echo` in removeAlert and check the response in Chrome developer tools Network panel.

Comment: The unset($_SESSION['alerts'][$alertindex]); is fired when the AJAX call is sent to the PHP file. I do not wish for anything to be returned so it will not show in the developer console. I also tried echo with some random text and it worked fine when called from the actual middleware file but did not work with the AJAX invocation.

Comment: Keep the echo and change your js like this: `$.ajax({...}).done(function(d){ alert(d) });` - if it shows your random string then ajax is working, you probably have another problem i guess.

Comment: I figured it out and am writing an answer for others to look at if they have the same problem. Thanks for the help though anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my own answer. It seems that because the AJAX call is technically going to another page and I am using sessions. I needed to put a session start at the top of the AJAX page so it is treated as part of the same session.

```
session_start();
```